# rticles package: block quote inside Rmarkdown header

Tags: r, r-markdown

I used the `R` package `rticles` to create the skeleton of an article formatted with the Journal of Statistical Software format. The header of the `.Rmd` file has a field `address`. I want the content of the latter to be broken down over multiple lines in the resulting pdf.

Problem: I can't get the `Rmarkdown` [block quotation](https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/authoring_pandoc_markdown.html%23raw-tex#block_quotations) to work inside the header. The default template generated by `rticles` contains the following code in the header

```
address: >
  First line
  Second line
```

`Rmarkdown` does not add escape characters (`\\`) to the `.tex` file: everything thus appears on a single line. 
I tried adding `\\` directly, but these are escaped to single backslashes.

How can I get a field to span over multiple lines?

A MWE can be obtained by running from `R`

```
#install.packages("rmarkdown")
#devtools::install_github("rstudio/rticles")
rmarkdown::draft("test.Rmd", template = "jss_article", package = "rticles")
```

and compiling the default template.